# Python 3 Web Scrape & Beautiful Soup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am starting out using Python and Beautiful soup.

I am practicing using the following code:-

```
import requests  
r = requests.get('https://www.autobarn.com.au/car-care-touring-accessories/car-care/washes?dir=asc&limit=48&order=name')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')  
results = soup.find_all('div', class_='product-details')

records = []  
for result in results:  
    SKU = result.find('small',class_='text-muted').text.strip()
    DESC = result.find('strong').text.strip().upper()
    PRICE = result.find ('span',class_='price')
    URL = result.find('a')['href']
    records.append((SKU, DESC, PRICE, URL))

import pandas as pd  
df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['SKU','DESCRIPTION', 'RRP', 'URL'])  
df.to_csv('d:\\WEB SCRAPE TEST 4.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

This works fine at getting the information I am after.

However, for price, it drags through all of the surrounding HTML info.

eg span class="price" id="product-price-1242"
span class="price">$6.99

This appears to be caused by 2 tags that are the same one after another:-
span class='price'
     span class='price'

While I can clean the price data up after in the csv file, is there any way to refine the code to just grab the price?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should fix the issue:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  

url = 'https://www.autobarn.com.au/car-care-touring-accessories/car-care/washes?dir=asc&limit=48&order=name'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')  
for result in soup.find_all('div', class_='product-details'): 
    SKU = result.find('small',class_='text-muted').text.strip()
    DESC = result.find('strong').text.strip().upper() 

    try:
        PRICE = result.select_one("[id^='product-price-'] span").text
    except AttributeError: PRICE = ""

    URL = result.find('a')['href']
    print(SKU, DESC, PRICE, URL)
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked well. I need to understand how you picked the html element and the syntax used. it was driving me crazy.

Comment: Or it should work as well `PRICE = result.find(lambda item:item.get('id')).find(class_='price').text`.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```
PRICE = result.find('span',class_='price').find('span',class_='price').text
```

You also have to decide how you want to handle the case where there is no price available. Maybe something like this:

```
if result.find('span',class_='price') is None:
    PRICE = "N/A"
else:
    PRICE = result.find('span',class_='price').find('span',class_='price').text
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Unfortunately, it returned - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' . I like the suggestion on the no price though.

Comment: Yes, that's going to happen for the items missing price information, hence the latter part.